# java.lang.RuntimeException -> Error while launching the CanHub Image Cropper

Tags: android, kotlin, compiler-errors, android-jetpack-compose

I am implementing the CanHub Image Cropper for an app in Android Studio. This is the screen where I use it, after receiving the Uri from another screen :

```kotlin
fun Cropper(textUri: String?, navController : NavHostController) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

    val imageUri = mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)

    imageUri.value = textUri?.toUri()

    val imageCropper = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        CropImageContract()
    ) { result ->
        if (result.isSuccessful) {
            val encodedUri = Uri.encode(
                result.uriContent!!
                    .toString()
                    .replace('%', '|')
            )
            navController.popBackStack()
            navController.navigate(AppScreens.SecondScreenImage.route + "/$encodedUri")
        } else {
            val exception = result.error
        }
    }
                    
                Button(onClick = { imageCropper.launch(
                    CropImageContractOptions(
                        imageUri.value,
                        CropImageOptions(
                            fixAspectRatio = true,
                            outputCompressFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG
                        )
                    )
                ) }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0xFF2D59F5))){
                    Text(
                        text = "Recortar",
                        fontFamily = Inter,
                        fontSize = 15.sp,
                        color = Color(0xFF000000),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried executing the app, but I got this error ->    `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vintis/com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`